# Running 'top' with 'Irix mode' off in batch mode

Tags: cpu-usage, top, batch-processing

Can anyone tell me how I can tweak the following top command so that it always runs in Solaris mode in a batch mode operation?

```
top -d 3 -n 2 -b -p <PID>
```

I need 'top' to output a process' CPU usage that had already been divided by the total number of CPUs, and as far as I know, that can be achieved with the 'I' toggle (Irix mode), but it only seems to be available in interactive operation (not in batch operation).

So I was wondering if this is indeed the case, or does anyone know any workaround for what I intended to achieve?

Thanks!

PS. OS: RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.

Comment: By the way, it's Irix **or** Solaris mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in a file called `$HOME/.toprc` or edit the existing one so it has `Mode_irixps=0` for off or `Mode_irixps=1` for on:

```
    RCfile for "top with windows"      # shameless braggin'
    Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=0, Delay_time=3.000, Curwin=0
```

Or you can set all your toggles, field selections and window settings in `top` the way you want them and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>W</kbd> to write the rc file for you.